# C++ Converting nanoseconds to milliseconds

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I am trying to monitor the time a section of code takes to run in both nano seconds and milliseconds and i have the nanoseconds working and i am now trying to do a duration_cast to turn the nanoseconds into milliseconds but it isn't working it just outputs 0 and the code for the duration cast doesn't seem to run.

```
// Get start time
const auto startTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

 // function here

// Get end time
const auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const auto durationNS = (endTime - startTime).count();
const auto int_ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(endTime - startTime);
const auto durationMS = int_ms.count();
```

At the bottom you can see where i am doing my duration cast but it isn't working any advice?

Comment: @cigien i've removed the unnecessary code.

Comment: What time are you getting in nanoseconds?

Comment: Why not just use a division by 10^6?

Comment: What do you mean by "Isn't working"? What's the result you're getting, and what do you expect?

Comment: [Works for me](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/AHq7vc).

Comment: It outputs 0 milliseconds but it should show 0.04 if my nanoseconds was 40000

Comment: You realize `int` cannot store `0.04`, right?

Comment: @Delta_G, Doing the math manually is error-prone and simply dividing by 10⁶ hides the fact that you're truncating. Chrono does lossless conversions implicitly and makes you explicitly decide to use lossy ones. In both cases, the math is done correctly and performantly.

Comment: But it would get an answer and you'd be able to explain that answer.  Right now you don't get an answer and you can't see the code that isn't giving you one.  One of us has an error and the other doesn't.  Who is more error prone?

Comment: i've fixed it now just made a bit of a stupid mistake.

Comment: No mistakes are stupid. Glad you figured out the solution. :)

Comment: @Delta_G, Dividing by a million would give you the same answer of 0 without any indication of truncation. The only way it doesn't give you 0 is if you introduce floating-point types somewhere. But you can also introduce floating-point types to chrono to have it go back to implicit conversions again with proper fractional results.

Comment: You could pick the appropriate type in your code and you could see what type you picked.  If the answer got truncated you'd be able to see that it was because your variable type was int and change to double.  Figuring out what some other API does is the difficult part.  As evidenced by the difficulty you had.  See the fact that you even had to ask this question makes my point.  You can't say that this is easier and less error prone when it was harder for you and caused errors where there wouldn't have been.

Comment: How do I know by looking at these calls whether something gets truncated or not?  I'd have to go through some API to figure that out.  With a division statement I could see it immediately and know the problem with no digging.  You can't simultaneously be having a hard time using something and be claiming that it is easier.

Comment: The fact that you need an explicit cast in there at all tells you that it's not a lossless conversion. Conversion by division tells you nothing; it looks the same either way. Your argument is based on the reader seeing a division and thinking to check for loss. I'd say it's much easier seeing an explicit cast and thinking to check for loss (otherwise the cast shouldn't be there) rather than wasting my time checking every single lossless conversion as well.

Comment: That doesn't even begin on the fact that people can _and do_ make silly mistakes when they do math. Multiplying instead of dividing happens because we're only human. It doesn't happen when you tell chrono to do the math for you because it's already been tested. You're very clearly converting from nanoseconds to milliseconds here. You know that conversion will be the correct result without worrying about which operation and factor. Because you had to call it out explicitly, you know it might not be the result you want and that you need to make sure you can accept the lossiness.

Comment: I'd highly recommend watching [Howard's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P32hvk8b13M) on the matter. He no doubt does a much better job than I do at explaining how the library helps the user to prevent mistakes. The talk starts with durations, the most straightforward part of the API. (And yes, I'm aware I keep saying "you know" in relation to the basic guarantees the library gives you. If you're using an API, you should _at least_ know that. Not knowing that is like not knowing that integer division truncates when you go to use it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
const auto endTime = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
const auto durationNS = (endTime - startTime).count();
std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> fp_ms = endTime - startTime;
const auto durationMS = fp_ms.count();
```

Above code works.